# capture the seconds forwarded or seconds re-winded

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

How could I capture the seconds forwarded or seconds re-winded in a HTML video?

```
$('#match').on('timeupdate',function(event) {

                // convert time to HH:MM:SS 
                //playing = true;
            });
```

For example video was playing at 45 seconds and I re-winded the video to 20 seconds. I need to know the difference : `45-20` = `25`

Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the latest current time in the callback, and when the difference is not +1, handle it:

```
last_current_time = 0;
$('#match').on('timeupdate',function(event) {
  var new_current_time = this.currentTime;
  var difference = new_current_time - last_current_time;
  if (difference != 1) {
    // Handle seeks here.
  }
  last_current_time = new_current_time;
});
```